# Is there a way to pass a variable as a singleton when querying XML?

Tags: sql-server

First time I'm working with XML, and seem to have trouble passing a variable to the singleton of XML query. The error that shows when I execute the query is "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal"

I have set the variable to data type varchar. What am I missing here?

```
----Inside LOOP----
SELECT @count = @count + 1

select 
a.XMLData.value('(//FlightInfo/TailNumber/text())['''+ @count +''']', 'varchar(100)') TaiNumber
from
XMLwithOpenXML a
```

Is there an easier way to go through XML nodes to amend those nodes that have incorrect/missing data?

I'm trying to traverse the "TailNumber" nodes, and then using some kind of join or where clause to update the node value with the correct TailNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, SQL Server still doesn't support the `position()` function as an output, only as a filtering criterion. As such, there is no easy way to number the nodes in their natural order. All solutions I've seen calculate the position of each node by counting all preceding nodes, producing essentially a semi-cartesian which kills all hopes for performance on a decently-sized XML.

You can, however, use a rather dirty trick which I employed some 8 years ago. You can generate a monotonous sequence of numbers and use them to find nodes in corresponding positions. The code below illustrates the approach:

```
-- Sample data
declare @t table (
  Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  XMLData xml not null
);

insert into @t (XMLData)
values (N'<r>
  <Item>First Value</Item>
  <Item>Second</Item>
</r>'),
(N'<r>
  <Item>Another One</Item>
  <Item>123456</Item>
  <Item>The last</Item>
</r>');

declare @NodeCount int;

-- Get the largest amount of nodes among the rows of interest
select @NodeCount = max(t.XMLData.value('count(/r/Item)', 'int'))
from @t t;

select t.Id, n.RN, i.c.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [NodeValue]
from @t t
  cross join (
    -- Generate a number sequence for each /r/Item node in every row
    select top (@NodeCount) row_number() over(order by (select null)) as [RN]
    from sys.all_objects
  ) n
  -- Get N-th node
  cross apply t.XMLData.nodes('/r/Item[position() = sql:column("n.RN")]') i(c)
order by t.Id, n.RN;
```

Just be careful about running it against a table with several million rows and / or big XML blobs. It runs pretty neat in this example, but I have no idea how efficient it will be in real-world cases. If your XMLs are big, or you have plenty of rows to query, a better solution might be to pre-process the XML by adding node numbers as attributes using a language other than SQL. A CLR function, for example, might be much better for this.

---

P.S. Still, should be faster than a loop...

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. Yes, I am using large data sets -- in the thousands to millions of rows. I've tried another approach which was loading the XML data into SSIS and then correcting some of the column data, and then exporting them out using the XSD as a guide. Now, my next challenge is exporting large XMLs -- I've tried several ways but to no avail, if you can check it out here, please let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890469/saving-large-data-into-xml-from-mssql-tried-several-ways-but-it-always-gets-cu