# Saving large data into XML from SQL Server. Tried several ways, but it always gets cut

Tags: sql-server

I've loaded some data using SSIS, and I want to export it as XML using a particular XSD. I've looked around, there's no way to just tell SQL Server "Hey here's my data with the same column names as this XSD, so now generate using this XSD"

As I've read, you need to open the XSD and do it yourself, so I did.

The SQL query is quite long, but it goes something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ---HEADER NODE LEVEL 1
    (SELECT ...
     FROM dbo.[HEADER]
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
    ----ACCOUNTLISTS NODE LEVEL 1
    ----ACCOUNTINFO NODE LEVEL 2 (THERE CAN BE SEVERAL CHILD NODES FOR 1 ACCOUNTLISTS NODE)
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         NULL as N, 
         (SELECT
              COLUMN1
              COLUMN2
          FROM 
              ACCOUNTINFO A
          INNER JOIN 
              ACCOUNTINFOLISTS B on A.ID = B.INFO_ID)
      FROM  
          ACCOUNTINFOLISTS
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
)
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Ledger'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

When I run it, there's no syntax error. Now I just want to check that it's actually correct.

Results to grid always out of memory if I run the whole thing.

If I run a section of it, it's fine. I've tried results to file and then saving it as "SAMPLE.XML"

But then when I do that, it's practically empty - only the first few lines are shown, and then gets cut.

How do I output it as a file so that I can check the contents in text editor or something?

Comment: Use BCP or Powershell.  EG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150672/export-xml-data-using-bcp-command-in-sql-server

Comment: If you're running out of memory for a singleXML result, just how large is it? SSMS is a 32bit application, so you can have up to 2GB of memory used by it. If that's your only query window that's something like a 1.6GB XML file.

Comment: @Larnu, I don't know how big it is because it isn't coming out. Always cut at less than 543 bytes. I would expect that if it did get cut, it would get cut at a bigger size? The only error it's throwing at me now is out of memory exception error

Comment: The statement doesn't look valid. For example, there is no `for xml` clause in the innermost subquery. Also, columns names are not comma-separated, which means SQL Server will treat the second one as an alias for the first. And it's not correlated with the outer levels, which means you are getting a cartesian product - it may explain why it always runs out of memory.